# How to find the length of every word in a string?

Tags: c, tokenize, c-strings, string-length

I wrote a code that takes a sentence and outputs every each word in a line. But I also want to write the size of each word next to it.

**Input:**

```
Hi my name is
```

**Current output:**

```
Hi
my
name
is
```

**Desired output:**

```
Hi(2)
my(2)
name(4)
is(2)
```

**My current Code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX 100

int main(void) {

    int c = 0;
    size_t n = 0;

    printf("\n Enter a sentence.\n\n input: ");

    /* read up to 100 characters from stdin, print each word on a line */
    while (n < MAX && (c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n')
    {
        if (c == ' ')
            printf("\n");
        else
            printf("%c", c);
        n++;
    }
    printf("\n");

    if (n == MAX) /* read and discard remaining chars in stdin */
        while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);

    return 0;
}
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Glad to see you are declaring `int c` rather `char c`.

Comment: No need to call the *variadic* `printif` to output a single character. That's what `putchar (c);` is for. (now when you output your length, you will need a conversion)

Answer (score 2):

For completeness a different approach reading the whole input in one call and then tokenising it:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX (100)

int main(void) 
{
  int result = EXIT_SUCCESS; /* Be optimistic. */ 
  char s[MAX +1];

  printf("\n Enter a sentence.\n\n input: ");

  /* read up to 100 characters from stdin, print each word on a line */

  if (NULL == fgets(s, sizeof s, stdin))
  {
    if (ferror(stdin))
    {
      perror("fgets() failed");
      result = EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
  }
  else
  {
    s[strcspn(s, "\r\n")] = '\0'; /* chop off carriage return, line feed, if any */

    for (char * pc = strtok(s, " "); NULL != pc; pc = strtok(NULL, " "))
    {
      printf("%s (%zu)\n", pc, strlen(pc));
    }
  }

  return result;
}
```

As the read buffer is never explicitly used the following variation is possible as well:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX (100)

int main(void) 
{
  int result = EXIT_SUCCESS; /* Be optimistic. */ 

  printf("\n Enter a sentence.\n\n input: ");

  {
  /* read up to 100 characters from stdin, print each word on a line */    
    char * pc = fgets((char[MAX+1]), MAX+1, stdin);
    if (NULL == pc)
    {
      if (ferror(stdin))
      {
        perror("fgets() failed");
        result = EXIT_FAILURE;
      }
    }
    else
    {
      pc[strcspn(pc, "\r\n")] = '\0'; /* chop off carriage return, line feed, if any */

      for (pc = strtok(pc, " "); NULL != pc; pc = strtok(NULL, " "))
      {
        printf("%s (%zu)\n", pc, strlen(pc));
      }
    }
  }

  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have one more variable and print out when you hit space.

```
size_t len = 0;

/* read up to 100 characters from stdin, print each word on a line */
while (n < MAX && (c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n')
{
    if (c == ' ') {
        printf("(%u)\n", len);
        len = 0;
    }
    else {
        len++;
        printf("%c", c);
    }
    n++;
}
```

Comment: Why are you checking `n < MAX`? The words are not being stored in an array? (I guess that would be your question for the OP)

Comment: @DavidRankin-ReinstateMonica I don't know, OP had it already.

Comment: I figured it was just a copy issue, but absent storing something somewhere (or just wanting to limit the read to 100-chars arbitrarily), it's kinda just hanging out there.

Comment: @DavidRankin-ReinstateMonica Yeah, even I'm not sure! I will work on it immediately once OP responds! Thank you.

Comment: @kiranBiradar I don't actually get the solution. can you please explain more?

Comment: @IWawa We are just maintaining one more counter to count the number of characters  in each word and we will print it out once you get the space.

Comment: @lWawa - you are using your loop as a *state loop* where you have two possible states `if (c == ' ')` where you are at the 1st whitespace between words where you output the length of the previous word and reset `len = 0;` The other state is `c != ' '` where you simply output the character. (you should probably add `if (c == ' ' || c == '\n')` to not include the `'\n'` in the count (and break the loop at that point), and keep a `int inword = 1/0` state too for inword/not in word to handle multiple whitespace)

Comment: C requires the use of the `z` *length modifier* when `printf`ing `size_t`s.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the good answer by [@kiranBiradar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4431643/kiran-biradar), you may want to add an additional variable that allows you to track whether you are *in-a-word* reading characters or *outside-a-word* reading *whitespace*. (using a simple `int` value as a *flag* set to `1` (true) for in-word or `0` (false) not-in-word is all you need) This will allow you to ignore leading whitespace, multiple included whitespace, or trailing whitespace in your input, e.g., if your input was similar to:

```
"   my       dog   has      fleas   and my   cat has   none  "
```

Unless you are keeping track of the state of your read, whether you are *in-word / not-in-word*, you will be outputting multiple occurrences of `"(0)\n"` each time a whitespace character is read. By keeping a flag of whether you are *in / not-in* a word and setting it zero when you encounter your first whitespace after being in-word reading non-whitespace characters allows you to only output the length once on the first whitespace encountered.

Additionally, conditioning your read on `c != '\n'` will skip outputting the length of the final word, unless you include additional code after you exit your read loop.

Also by including `<ctype.h>` you have the `isspace()` macro available to check for *all* whitespace (e.g, `space, tab, newline, backspace, vertical-tab`, etc...) It greatly simplifies your conditional checks.

Putting it altogether you could do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>      /* for isspace() */

int main (void) {

    int c = 0, in = 0, len = 0;             /* char, in/out flag, length */

    fputs ("enter text: ", stdout);         /* prompt for text */
    fflush (stdout);                        /* (optional), but recommended */

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {        /* loop reading chars until EOF */
        if (isspace (c)) {                  /* if input is space */
            if (in) {                       /* check if in-word */
                printf ("(%d)\n", len);     /* output (len) */
                len = 0;                    /* reset len zero */
                in = 0;                     /* set in flag zero (false) */
            }
            if (c == '\n')                  /* if space is \n */
                break;                      /* break read loop */
        }
        else {  /* if not whitespace */
            putchar (c);                    /* output char */
            len++;                          /* increment length */
            in = 1;                         /* set in flag 1 (true) */
        }
    }
}
```

(**note:** there is no reason to limit your read to `n < MAX` unless you simply want to arbitrarily limit your read of characters to the first 100-characters. There is no array being filled or other storage being occupied by the character `c` (aside from it's one byte). You could read billions if your input contained them)

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/getchar_word_len
enter text:      my       dog   has      fleas   and my   cat has   none
my(2)
dog(3)
has(3)
fleas(5)
and(3)
my(2)
cat(3)
has(3)
none(4)
```

Look over both answers and let either of us know if you have further questions. If you are confused by the logic, take out an 8.5x11 sheet of paper and work through the logic of the loop for each character starting at the beginning of your input. It will make sense by the time you work through the first word.

Comment: Yes, but I had to break the habit of declaring all function variables between the `()` and the `{...}` -- that took a while `:)`

Comment: @DavidRankin-ReinstateMonica Thank you, I will study the code and try to understand it.

Comment: The 8.5x11 sheet of paper and a pencil to keep track of what character you are working through the loop with is key to sorting it out and helping it sink it. (no better way to learn `:)`